# Increase the expiry period of reset password link in firebase 3

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently I am using >3 version firebase SDK.

In the new api, `auth.sendPasswordResetEmail` sends a reset link in the mail which expires in 2-3 hours.

Is it possible to enable a 24 hour just like old version? and if so, how?

Comment: the expiration time have changed from firebase 2.x to 3.x so i guess this wont be possible.

Comment: *firebaser here* There currently is no way to change the expiration time for the password reset link. The use-case is that a user asks to reset their password and they are expected to follow up in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Thanks Adolfosrs and Frank .Will it possible to use old firebase sdk and new sdk together.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there really no way to control the length the password reset validity period?  It makes sense to default to something short, but for lower-security use cases where user friendliness outweighs security benefit there should be flexibility.  The worst part is when creating a new user, the initial link they receive expires in 50 minutes.  This is a terrible experience for end users and wastes time for both the admin and end user, especially if their schedules aren't in sync such as if in different time zones.

Comment: Totally agree with @g491, this can be a waste of time. I guess the assumption is that the user triggers it, but it could happens that the admin does it for them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not currently possible to set the expiration time for any of the generated email links. They don't publish the expiration times either. They said it **about** 1 hour.

Read more:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1884