# Increase firebase's oob codes expiration time

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, authentication, gcloud

I'm using **server-side generated firebase's oob codes** (like email verification and password reset) for implementing an **organization/member pattern** within my application.
I want to be able, as an organization owner, to invite members, who will receive an email containing a link so they can sign-up for the first time for my application, getting its email verified and performing a first-time-sign-in password reset.

My problem is, the oob codes have too little validity time for my use, and my invited members are getting "**action code has expired**" errors 99% of the time.

I want to know if there is a way to **increase the expiration time for the oob codes**, **avoiding me having to reengineer the whole auth stack**. Also, **any suggestion for better ways to achieve this would be very welcome**. =)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't change the expiration times as far as I know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674497/increase-the-expiry-period-of-reset-password-link-in-firebase-3

Comment: Seems like this is a dupe and I failed to find the prev responses... My bad!
Thanks for the reply, Frank.